# 401 unauthorized error while trying to download an image

Tags: c#, .net, webclient

I am trying to download an image from a URL using the following code:

```
using (System.Net.WebClient webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
    NetworkCredential Cred = new NetworkCredential();
    Cred.UserName = "user";
    Cred.Password = "password^";

    webClient.Credentials = Cred;
    imageBytes = webClient.DownloadData(s);
}
```

However, I get the error : The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
There is no inner exception. I am giving my crendentials, and I am able to download the image when I paste them directly to IE.
I am just not able to figure out what is causing this.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/2150161/1218281

Comment: oh man! thanks a bunch.. I have been on this for so long.

Answer (score 0):

Setting webClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true; solved my issue